# Round with floor problem in Objective-C

Tags: c, objective-c, math, floating-point

I am calculating g with e and s, which are all doubles. After that I want to cut off all digits after the second and save the result in x, for example:

g = 2.123 => x = 2.12

g = 5.34995 => x = 5.34

and so on. I Use...

```
g = 0.5*e + 0.5*s;
x = floor(g*100)/100;
```

...and it works fine most of the time. But sometimes I get strange results. For example:

e = 3.0
s = 1.6
g = 2.30
but x = 2.29!!!

So I tried to track down the error:

```
g = 0.5*e + 0.5*s;
NSLog(@"%f",g);
```

gives me g = 2.30

```
g = g * 100;
NSLog(@"%f",g);
```

gives me g = 230.0

```
x = floor(g);
NSLog(@"%f",x);
```

results in x = 229.0 !!!

I don't get it! Help please! :-)

Comment: For your perusal: *What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic* http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: This has nothing to do with Objective-C, or even C, really.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to store these in only 2 decimal digits?

Comment: Could be worse; your floating point error could be responsible for 28 deaths. https://www.gao.gov/products/IMTEC-92-26

Answer (score 3):

This will be due to floating point calculations.

Your calculation

```
g * 100
```

already brings back

229.99999999999997

From where your issue stems.

Have a look at [INFO: Precision and Accuracy in Floating-Point Calculations](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/125056)

Also have a look at [Floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)

**Accuracy problems**

> The fact that floating-point numbers
>   cannot precisely represent all real
>   numbers, and that floating-point
>   operations cannot precisely represent
>   true arithmetic operations, leads to
>   many surprising situations. This is
>   related to the finite precision with
>   which computers generally represent
>   numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have a quick solution to avoid this problem?

Comment: Have a look at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/921a8ffc-9829-4145-bdc9-a96c1ec174a5/. try decimal vs double for precision if you can. And maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c

Comment: the decimal type is a .Net type; OP is using Objective-C & the Cocoa API (note the call to `NSLog`), so decimal isn't an option.

Comment: Sorry, when i originally posted the answer it also stated c#, please see the revisions to the question.

Answer (score 2):

As others have already mentioned, this is due to the limited precision of floating point numbers in computers. These imprecisions show up everywhere a hard yes/no decision about a floating point number is made. In order to resolve the problem, you can add/subtract a small number to find an answer that is correct up to a certain accuracy.

You may find functions like these useful:

```
#define ACC 1e-7

double floorAcc( double x ) { return floor(x + ACC);}
double ceilAcc( double x ) { return ceil(x - ACC); }
bool isLessThanAcc( double x, double y ) { return (x + ACC) < y; }
bool isEqualAcc( double x, double y ) { return (x + ACC) > y && (x - ACC) < y; }
```

Of course, these work only in a limited number range. When working with very small or very large numbers, you need to pick another value for ACC.

Note that the value of 'ACC' is in general dependent on the accuracy of the numbers in your application, **not** on the value of x. For example, comparing two numbers `a` and `b` for equality can be done in two ways: `isEqualAcc(a, b)` and `isEqualAcc(a-b, 0)`. You would want the same result from both ways, even though in the second way the number x is likely much smaller.

Comment: Surely ACC should be calculable and not just hard coded? If we know the size of `x` can't we determine the size of potential floating point errors?

Comment: I did notice `__FLT_EPSILON__` in C documentation; perhaps useful here.

Comment: ACC is almost always dependent on the general accuracy of the numbers in your application, not relative to x. See added explanation in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible approach using intermediate integer results:

```
double e = 3.0;
double s = 1.6;

NSInteger e1 = e * .5 * 100.0; // 150
NSInteger s1 = s * .5 * 100.0; // 80

double x = (e1 + s1)/100.0; // 2.3
```